# history.push is changing url but not view (using forcerefresh:True not working) in react router 6

Tags: reactjs

i am using latest version of react and react router dom v 6

i am developing registration system and after successful registration want to navigate to login. but history.push is not working in redux action page

here is code

history.js

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
export default createBrowserHistory({ forceRefresh: true });
```

authSlice.js

```
import history from "../../history";

export const register = (user) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const userData = {
      username: user.username,
      email: user.email,
      contact: user.contact,
      password: user.password,
    };
    const response = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:4000/auth/register",
      userData
    );

    if (response) {
      // console.log("data is ", response.data);
      dispatch(registerSuccess(response.data));
      toast.success("Registration Successful. You can now login");
      history.push("/signin");
    } else {
      console.log("error");
      dispatch(registerFailure());
      toast.error("registration failed");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response.status === 400) toast.error(error.response.data);
    dispatch(registerFailure());
  }
};
```

though user is getting registered in db and url also changing but not the view

Answer (score 0):

I was also searching for the same answer but failed to find one that worked, ended up using `window.location.reload()` as a fix.

Comment: where to use it ... i used after history.push but no result

Comment: Yes it should be after `history.push("/wherever-you-want")`. If you are not seeing the component being render(even after the reload) than make sure it is available on the route you are specifying.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<Router>` in route file to synchronize it with react-router.

Answer (score 0):

If you getting issue in using history so you can use useHistoy() hook instead of createBrowserHistory or you can use withRouter()

Like

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

const register = (user) => async (dispatch) => {
  const { match, location, history } = user;
  try {
    const userData = {
      username: user.username,
      email: user.email,
      contact: user.contact,
      password: user.password,
    };
    const response = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:4000/auth/register",
      userData
    );

if (response) {
  // console.log("data is ", response.data);
  dispatch(registerSuccess(response.data));
  toast.success("Registration Successful. You can now login");
  history.push("/signin");
} else {
  console.log("error");
  dispatch(registerFailure());
  toast.error("registration failed");
}
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response.status === 400) toast.error(error.response.data);
    dispatch(registerFailure());
  }
}
export default withRouter(register);
```

Comment: but i am using it outside react component...in redux actions... not able to use hooks outside react

Comment: Then use withRouter

Comment: or you can pass history on action payload so you can use useHistory.
And their is one more method to resolved this issue just create extra state in reducer and change it when action go to reducer with data and re-render that page on the basis of new state using useEffect(()=>{},[state]) to give new state as dependencies and then redirect on the basis of condition if(state){ history.push('/home')}